# add columns in gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which columns are binded dynamically..column count may be 7 or 12 or 17.it depends on user selection.I want below columns to be added in rowdatabound method.First problem is that Iam unable to set column names in rowdatabound and second is that column count coming 0 and third is that columns which are made invisible are unable to be accessed.If anybody knows how can we achieve the same through html table..If somebody could find time and help me out please..

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Services"  DataField="Services" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="12%"> </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category"  DataField="Category" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="12%" > </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="ALTA"  DataField="1_ALTA" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"   />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="HPLAN"  DataField="1_HPLAN" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField  HeaderText="HOSP"  DataField="1_HOSP" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="OTHER" DataField="1_OTHER"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OTHERSCOLOR" Visible="false" DataField="1_OthersColor" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>

    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="ALTA"  DataField="2_ALTA" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="2%" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="HPLAN" DataField="2_HPLAN"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="2%" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="HOSP" DataField="2_HOSP"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="2%" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="OTHER" DataField="2_OTHER"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OTHERSCOLOR" DataField="2_OthersColor" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>

    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="ALTA" DataField="3_ALTA"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"  />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="HPLAN" DataField="3_HPLAN"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="HOSP" DataField="3_HOSP"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="OTHER" DataField="3_OTHER"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OTHERSCOLOR" DataField="3_OthersColor" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#e34e08" ItemStyle-Width="2%"/>

</Columns>
```

Comment: Share your code in which user makes a choice and the point where you are trying to add new columns.

Comment: Based on your list of fields you need to rethink your solution, a GridView may not be your best option.  Gridview are perfectly suited for displaying and editing existing data.  It's less suited for data insertion. And poorly suited for dynamic column creation combined with data collection. There is a lot of repetition.  Knowing nothing of your requirements and seeing only what you have listed, those 5 fields can exist in a separate FormView that can collect data repetitively as your user requirements need.